# How to Transition width/height from center in a table layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I have a flex layout of items which mimics the look of a table. The idea is to show them all like this but when you hover the hovered item needs to expand in all 4 directions overlapping other items while staying centered. When the mouse leaves the item then it should collapse back to its original size. However, on both mouse enter and mouse leave the transition should be smooth. I got it to work with mouse in, but cannot figure out how to make it smooth on mouse out.

You will see in example below that the mouse out is not smooth because it loses its index value and without that index value I cannot get it to overlap. Is there another way to do this? Javascript solutions are also welcome but not preferred.

It seems when I paste the html/css into SO the hover doesn't work at all.  At least on my browser so I'm leaving a js fiddle link where you can see my problem. Just note that when the mouse leaves the box it loses z-index value and thus the right side of that box goes behind the next box while the left side stays on top and transitions properly.

Here is JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/1gr036k5/1/

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper div {
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.wrapper.two div span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.wrapper div:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}

.wrapper div span:hover {
  opacity: 100%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
  left: -10%;
  top: -10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div><span></span></div>
  <div><span></span></div>
  <div><span></span></div>
  <div><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here. Centering an element is pretty simple but **not** when there are other siblings which have be taken into account. In additon, some of the properties you are trying to transtion **are not animatable**. such as `position`. Not saying it can't be done but you're gonna ned a tonne of JS and computed values and positions.

Comment: @Paulie_D Well, I just had an idea i'm trying to see if it will work. I can maybe use js to control z-index only and rest stays on css. Still playing with it to try and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper div {
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:relative;
}

.wrapper div span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  opacity:0;
}

.wrapper div:hover {
}

.wrapper div:hover span{
 transform: scale(2, 2);
 opacity:1;
 z-index:4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div><span></span></div>
  <div><span></span></div>
  <div><span></span></div>
  <div><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, notice how when you mouse out your right side doesn't transition back at at all; it just gets tucked behind the element to its right so it gives a look of it being sliced off.

Comment: It's because i've added overflow:hidden in parent tag..  you can remove that. but in that case you'll see scrollbar